# y-Shear Matrix as a combination of basic transformation?

Tags: graphics

I tried to know and searches very much but I didn't find for y-direction shear [1,0,0]
      [shy,1,0]
      [0,0,1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer at http://web.archive.org/web/20060914224155/http://web.archive.org:80/web/20041029003853/http://www.j3d.org/matrix_faq/matrfaq_latest.html#Q43

In case the link gets broken somehow, here is the relevant part:

A shearing matrix is used to make a 3D model appear to slant sideways.
  For example, "italic" text requires each character to slant towards the
  right.
  In three dimensions six possible shearing directions exist:

```
o shear X by Y
o shear X by Z
o shear Y by X
o shear Y by Z
o shear Z by X
o shear Z by Y
```

All six shearing directions may be combined into a single matrix:

```
    | 1    Syx  Szx  0 |
    |                  |
    | Sxy  1    Szy  0 |
M = |                  |
    | Sxz  Syz  1    0 |
    |                  |
    | 0    0    0    1 |
    |                  |

Where Sij implements a shear of I by J
Thus, Sxy shears X by Y
```

In theory, rotation in three dimensions may be considered a combination
  of six shearing directions.

Comment: I don't mean the meaning of shearing matrix I mean that matrix shear what does  it consist of the rotation and scaling and translate matrix?

Comment: I found my Answer in this link thank you https://cmake.org/pipermail/insight-users/2005-August/014409.html